# How to add class after replace class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually, I have a code given below.

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function() {
  return $('<div>', {
    html: $(this).html()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Actually, I replaced all `<p>` tags with `<div>` its working fine but now I want to add a class in `<div>` so how can I add this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `addClass()` method with generated element

```
return $('<div>', {html:$(this).html()}).addClass('thisClass')
```

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function() {
  return $('<div>', {
    html: $(this).html()
  }).addClass('thisClass')
});
```

```css
.thisClass {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>p1
</p>
<p>p2
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your function, add a `class` attribute, and that's a best practice:

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function() {
  return $('<div>', {
    html: $(this).html(),
    class: "myClass"
  })
});
```

```css
.myClass {color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this without `replaceWith()`. Adding this answer to let you know about the alternative so that it can be useful in future scenarios.

```js
$('p').html('<div class="newClass">'+$('p').html()+'</div>');
```

```css
.newClass{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some text 1
</p>
<p>Some text 2
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your class to your replaced `div`s during replacing you can do like the following:

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function() { return $('<div>').addClass("someClass").html($(this).html())});
```

```css
div.someClass
{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>p1
</p>
<p>p2
</p>
<p>p3
</p>
```

**But** if by the following sentence

> but now i want to add a class

you mean that you want to add class to the `div` elements that are replaced to `p` element after a while, then you can add some attribute to your replaced `div` so that you can recognize your replace `div` for example  I would add attribute `replaced="true"` to the replaced `div` and some where else i will get them all and add `someClass` to them:

```
$('p').replaceWith(function() { return $('<div>').attr("replaced","true").html($(this).html())});
```

**After a while some where else:**

```
$('div[replaced="true"]').addClass("someClass")
```

Working example:(Here we first replace `p` tags with `div` after that we add some `div` to our body, and at the end we add `someClass` to just replaced `div` tags:

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function() { return $('<div>').attr("replaced","true").html($(this).html())});

$('body').append($("<div>").html("hello"));
$('div[replaced="true"]').addClass("someClass")
```

```css
div.someClass
{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>p1
</p>
<p>p2
</p>
<p>p3
</p>
<div>temp
</div>
```